# Programatically incremenet and decrement cart item quantity in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

Programatically incremenet and decrement cart item quantity in magento 2.

Comment: in which page u want that @srg

Comment: in displaying the cart...actually i want to create an api for that..